# Apache FOP fox:external-document not working when using PDF file

Tags: java, apache-fop

I am trying to append an pdf document using Apache FOP `fox:external-document`, but it is throwing the following exception when using pdf type:

```
SEVERE: Image not available. URI: /pathToPdf/file.pdf. Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for /pathToPdf/file.pdf (See position 202:89)
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for /pathToPdf/file.pdf
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                ...
            </fo:layout-master-set>            

            <fox:external-document content-type="pdf" src="/pathToPdf/file.pdf"/>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using Apache FOP 2.3 and Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension property [`fox:external-document`](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html#external-document) is originally meant to insert *images* as pages in the pdf output.

In order to use it with pdf files too you need the [PDF Images Plug-In](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fop-pdf-images.html).

Just download and put (or link) the jar in the lib folder and everything should work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me when adding pdf from filesystem or resource:

```
Filesystem:
<fox:external-document src="url('file:D:///resource/test.pdf')"/>
Resource:
<fox:external-document src="url('file:resource/test.pdf')"/> 

Remember to add:
  xmlns:pdf="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/pdf"
and 
  xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"
```